# Getting error "INDEX WAS OUT OF BOUNDS" while retrieving check box for checking values selected from sql to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have been inserted with the checked values of check box to table by splitting them into different column, same as i want to retrieve values from the table to be checked into check box it is through the error

> "INDEX WAS OUT OF BOUNDS"

The code regarding is below

```
foreach (DataRow Recpt in ds.Tables[5].Rows)
{

        for (var i = 0; i <= chkPrdRecipients.Items.Count-1; i++)
        {

            var Recipients = Recpt["RecipientId"].ToString();
            Array arrRecipients = Recipients.Split(',');

            for (var j = 0; j <= Recipients.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (arrRecipients.GetValue(j).ToString().Trim().ToLower() ==
                    chkPrdRecipients.Items[i].Value.Trim().ToLower())
                {
                    chkPrdRecipients.Items[i].Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Please find a solution....

Comment: Quick note - it's much more idiomatic to write: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` than `for (int i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++)`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using the length of the *string* for the upper bound of `j`, instead of the length of the array. You'll get rid of this immediate error using:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arrRecipient.Length; j++)
```

However, the code would still be really ugly - why are you using `Array` instead of `string[]`? The code would be much simpler that way. I'd also rename the variables to follow normal conventions. For example:

```
foreach (DataRow recipientRow in ds.Tables[5].Rows)
{
    // We don't need to fetch this multiple times, or trim them each time.
    string[] recipients = ((string) recipientRow["RecipientId"])
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .ToArray();

    // It's possible that you could use a foreach loop here, but
    // we don't know the type of chkPrdRecipients...
    for (int i = 0; i < chkPrdRecipients.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = chkPrdRecipients.Items[i];
        foreach (var recipient in recipients)
        {
            if (recipient.Equals(item.Value.Trim(), 
                                 StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break; // No need to check the rest of the recipients
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I may suggest, instead of `foreach (var receipient)`, `recipients.Contains(item)` could help. What do you think?

Comment: hiii @Jon Skeet thx for that i still getting an error like 
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type System.String'."

Comment: @shahkalpesh: That won't work without making it case-insensitive, which is a bigger change.

Comment: @user2563416: If the `RecipientId` column is an `int`, why on earth are you treating it as a string? And why are you splitting that string by commas? Will there actually only ever be a single value? You haven't given us enough information here.